# How do I pass multiple values into a query string in my mongoose / mongodb schema?

Tags: mongodb, http, mongoose

According to [Atlas App Services (http.get)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/services/http-actions/http.get/), I've created a simple API that allows me to query documents using the equal sign "=".

E.g. (field is color and value is red)

```
https://www.example.com/toys?color=blue
```

Do you know how to pass multiple values into the URL query string? I've tried to query my api using [https://www.example.com/toys?color=['blue','red']](https://www.example.com/toys?color=%5B%27blue%27,%27red%27%5D) but it does not work. What is the correct URL query string in this case? So that I can adjust my conditions accordingly.

My mongo shell command in this case works so I'm sure mongoDB accepts multiple values.. e.g.

```
query='{"toys": { "$in": ["blue","red"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple **JSON.stringify(toys)** in query string from Front End and JSON.parse(toys) the JSON in mongoDb.

**Example:**

color = ['blue', 'red'];

var arrStr = JSON.stringify(color);

var myLink = 'https://www.example.com/toys?color=' + arrStr;

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the query parameters in array format from the frontend as shown below.

```js
https://www.example.com/toys?color[]=blue&color[]=red
```

In your backend API, this array can be access as `req.query.color`.